# wxDataViewListCtrl on click item action not executing

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `wxDataViewListCtrl` which I bind for when a item is clicked as,

```
    Bind(wxEVT_DATAVIEW_SELECTION_CHANGED, &Browser::OnClickSampleView, this, BCID_SampleListView);
```

And the related function is,

```
void Browser::OnClickSampleView(wxDataViewEvent& event)
{
    std::cout << "\n Click Sample View \n";

    std::string selection = SampleListView->GetTextValue(SampleListView->GetSelectedRow(), 1).ToStdString();

    std::cout << selection << "\n";
}
```

But nothing happens when I click on a item, nothing prints to console no error. What am I doing wrong?

I have already tried binding it without the ID and with `SampleListView->Bind()` as well, no luck.

I asked this question on wxWidgets Forum, but no one there was able to figure out the problem, one person asked me to try this,

```
SampleListView->Bind(wxEVT_DATAVIEW_SELECTION_CHANGED, [this](wxDataViewEvent &e) { 
    wxLogDebug("dataviewevent row %d", SampleListView->ItemToRow(e.GetItem()));
});
```

and this works, it prints to the console fine,

```
18:07:06: Debug: dataviewevent row 0
18:07:07: Debug: dataviewevent row 1
18:07:09: Debug: dataviewevent row 2
18:07:10: Debug: dataviewevent row 3
```

Link to the project, on the line which has `Bind()` - https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/cpp-projects/-/blob/master/wxWidgets/SampleBrowser/src/Browser.cpp#L142

EDIT:

After experimenting a little with the app, I noticed that all buttons and everything that I'm catching event for stops working after I add a single entry to the wxDataViewListCtrl, so I investigated further and in the function which I'm using to add data to wxDataViewListCtrl, I'm inserting all that data to Sqlite3 database also, I noticed that If I comment that line, that inserts data to Sqlite3 database, everything works fine.

```
void Browser::OnClickDirCtrl(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    TagLib::FileRef File (DirCtrl->GetFilePath());
    TagLib::String Artist = File.tag()->artist();
    TagLib::String Album = File.tag()->album();
    TagLib::String Genre = File.tag()->genre();
    TagLib::String Title = File.tag()->title();
    TagLib::String Comment = File.tag()->comment();
    int Bitrate = File.audioProperties()->bitrate();
    int Channels = File.audioProperties()->channels();
    int Length = File.audioProperties()->lengthInMilliseconds();
    int LengthSec = File.audioProperties()->lengthInSeconds();
    int SampleRate = File.audioProperties()->sampleRate();
    
    std::string Path = DirCtrl->GetFilePath().ToStdString();
    
    char c = '/';
    std::string Filename = DirCtrl->GetFilePath().AfterLast(c).ToStdString();

    wxVector<wxVariant> Data;
    Data.clear();
    Data.push_back(false);
    Data.push_back(Filename);
    Data.push_back(TagLibTowx(Artist));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",Channels));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",LengthSec));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",SampleRate));
    Data.push_back(wxString::Format("%d",Bitrate));
    Data.push_back(TagLibTowx(Comment));

    SampleListView->AppendItem(Data);

    // db.InsertSample(0, Filename, Artist.to8Bit(), Channels, Length,
                    // SampleRate, Bitrate, Comment.to8Bit(), Path);

    wxString sample = db.GetSamplePathByFilename(std::string(Filename));
    std::cout << "Sample: " << sample << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see above I have commented out the line which inserts data to Sqlite3 database which is `db.InsertSample()` which looks like this

```
void Database::InsertSample(int Favorite, std::string Filename,
                            std::string SamplePack, int Channels, int Length,
                            int SampleRate, int Bitrate, std::string Comment,
                            std::string Path)
{
    try
    {
        rc = sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &DB);

        sql = "INSERT INTO SAMPLES (FAVORITE, FILENAME, SAMPLEPACK, CHANNELS, \
                                    LENGTH, SAMPLERATE, BITRATE, BITSPERSAMPLE, PATH) \
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &stmt, NULL);   // create the prepared statement
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, Favorite);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, Filename.c_str(), Filename.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, SamplePack.c_str(), SamplePack.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, Channels);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 5, Length);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 6, SampleRate);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 7, Bitrate);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, Comment.c_str(), Comment.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 9, Path.c_str(), Path.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            std::cout << "Not inserted data." << "\n";
        }
        
        rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error! Cannot insert data into table." << std::endl;
            sqlite3_free(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else if (rc == SQLITE_BUSY)
        {
            std::cout << "BUSY" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (rc == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (rc == SQLITE_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (rc == SQLITE_MISUSE)
        {
            std::cout << "MISUSE" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Data inserted successfully." << ErrorMessage << std::endl;
        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        std::cerr << exception.what();
    }
}
```

I can't say if something is wrong with the database or what at this point, I'm still looking, please if you see anything wrong let me know.

Link to the `Database.cpp` file - https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/cpp-projects/-/blob/master/wxWidgets/SampleBrowser/src/Database.cpp

Comment: This is too "magic" and "impossible" to be explained without being able to reproduce it, so you need to either provide the simplest possible test case showing the problem or use a debugger to determine what's going on yourself.

Comment: Here is a minimal example I made, its doing the exact same thing, the `wxDVC` and `Sqlite3` `InsertData()` are copied and modified to test the problem. You can run `meson build` then `meson compile -C build` and run the binary with `./build/wxDvcTest`. This works on Linux, can't say about windows or mac, - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vzzlawgYJhVfaLk5sPWJsP4Q2r1CIqDx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like everything is working as intended, its just that the `std::cout` statements stopped printing to the console, I was not flushing the stream after some print statements, but even after adding `std::endl` didn't fix the problem, so for now I switched all print statements to `wxLog`. So I think it is fixed.